# How to use pylint's run_pyreverse?

Tags: python, pylint, pyreverse

I want to use pylint.pyreverse in python 2.7.

I see info on how to use [pyreverse](https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/6883)

However, I don't see how the parameters are specified to use pylint's run_pyreverse method.

How do I use pylint.run_pyreverse?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `pyreverse -h` on the command line.

BTW, if `pylint` is installed along with anaconda, you probably should reinstall (upgrade) it (`pip install -U pylint`), otherwise the system cannot find `pyreverse`.

see http://pythonhosted.org/theape/documentation/developer/explorations/explore_graphs/explore_pyreverse.html